# BSP tree in blender

Tags: python

I'm working on a project in which I need to find out if there is polygon in the proximity of a point in space. I read somewhere that the binary space partition tree can be useful for this. I found a lot of theory but still, I don't understand how to implement it practically in Blender.

Can anyone give me a brief explanation, how to implement it or tell me if it is even useful for a problem that I'm dealing with, please?

Comment: The blender api provides such functionality, you can use [KD-trees](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.kdtree.html) or [BVH-trees](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.bvhtree.html) to deal with relations in space. If you deal with heavy meshes use [efficient data access to vert coordinates](https://blenderartists.org/t/efficient-copying-of-vertex-coords-to-and-from-numpy-arrays/661467)(use `foreach_get()`)

Comment: I tried KD tree but it takes only points in space, I need to detect any if there is any part of face nearby. For areas with dense vertices, it worked but it did not work for large faces.

Comment: Then you need BVH tree to get the closest face and a distance to it.

Comment: Thank you, It is working. You helped a lot.